# Unable to django start server after commited some migration files to smartgit

Tags: python, django

`enter code here`(kemgo-api-v2) ronnie@vax-PC-88:/var/www/html/kemgo-api-v2$ python manage.py runserver

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f22b50abcf8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mohit/.virtualenvs/kemgo-api-v2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 222, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mohit/.virtualenvs/kemgo-api-v2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 107, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/home/mohit/.virtualenvs/kemgo-api-v2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 159, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/home/mohit/.virtualenvs/kemgo-api-v2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/home/mohit/.virtualenvs/kemgo-api-v2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 48, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/mohit/.virtualenvs/kemgo-api-v2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 241, in build_graph
    self.graph.add_dependency(migration, key, parent)
  File "/home/mohit/.virtualenvs/kemgo-api-v2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 42, in add_dependency
    raise KeyError("Migration %s dependencies references nonexistent parent node %r" % (migration, parent))
KeyError: u"Migration storefront.0002_storeview dependencies references nonexistent parent node (u'km', u'0010_auto_20170327_0841')"
```

*0002_storeview.py*

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations
import django.utils.timezone


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('km', '0010_auto_20170327_0841'),
        ('storefront', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='StoreView',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('ip', models.GenericIPAddressField(default=b'', null=True, blank=True)),
                ('viewtype', models.CharField(default=b'1', max_length=1, null=True, blank=True, choices=[(b'1', b'View'), (b'2', b'Mobile'), (b'3', b'Website'), (b'4', b'Email'), (b'5', b'Contact Tab'), (b'6', b'TDS Download')])),
                ('source', models.CharField(default=b'IOS', max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)),
                ('status', models.CharField(default=b'0', max_length=1, null=True, blank=True, choices=[(b'0', b'Inactive'), (b'1', b'Active')])),
                ('created_date', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)),
                ('store', models.ForeignKey(related_name=b'storeview', to='km.Store')),
                ('user', models.ForeignKey(related_name=b'store_userview', to='km.User', null=True)),
            ],
            options={
            },
            bases=(models.Model,),
        ),
    ]
```

i have deleted the following files and then commit:
    globalmarket/migrations/**init**.py
    inquiry/migrations/**init**.py
    km/migrations/.gitignore
    km/migrations/0001_initial.py
    km/migrations/0002_store1.py
    km/migrations/0003_remove_storemodule_created_date.py
    km/migrations/0004_storemodule_created_date.py
    km/migrations/0005_delete_store1.py
    km/migrations/**init**.py
    km/migrations/back/.gitignore
    km/migrations_bck/.gitignore
    km/migrations_bck/0025_auto_20150224_1547.py.bak
    km/migrations_bck/0026_auto_20150225_0958.py.bak
    km/migrations_bck/0107_auto_20151023_0541.py.bak
    km/migrations_bck/@
    storefront/migrations/0001_initial.py
    storefront/migrations/0002_storeview.py
    storefront/migrations/**init**.py

Comment: You can't run server because have conflict in Data (migrations) you should show the lastest migration (0002) and models if it need

Comment: HI Nam, i am a beginner, please help me, which migration file should show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ex for migrate: my file: (0002_auto...)

```
 class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('svace', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RenameField(
            model_name='application',
            old_name='type',
            new_name='application_type',
        ),
    ]
```

The **dependencies** will so the lastest update (before you make this new migrate). In your case, check the link (*/project_name/app_name/migrations) and give me the list of file (show the data of 0002.xxx file too)

Comment: i am unable to send you the code my file, stackoverflow comment section saying that is too long, so where to show my code to you ?

Comment: as i see, the update need 2 old version ~> You have to take control of it. Which data do you want and do you need it. You should to check it yourself (if you don't have data, you can create it all again)

Answer (score 0):

Error message seems pretty clear:

```
KeyError: u"Migration storefront.0002_storeview dependencies references nonexistent parent node (u'km', u'0010_auto_20170327_0841')"
```

Maybe you forgot to commit a file (`0010_auto_20170327_0841.py`) to your git repository, or this file has been deleted for a reason. Anyway, when applying migration, the migration `0002_storeview.py` from application `storefront` try to locate its parent (the previous migration) but can't find the corresponding file

Comment: Hi, Antwane, thanks for for your help, actually there was some migrations files (with missing status) in my smartgit, which i committed, then this problem occurred, please help me out this.

Comment: What is the solution if i deleted the file ?

Comment: i have deleted the following files and then commit:

Comment: So you can restore it from your git history

Answer (score 0):

i got to know what was the problem,
Previously i was connected to the local database, but now while i was running the migration with other database server, to migration got conflited,

Solution: I commented the dependency code from the migration file and ran the fake migration.

dependencies = [
        #('km', '0010_auto_20170327_0841'),
        ('storefront', '0001_initial'),
    ]

But i am still looking for the systematic solution for that if any migration conflicts comes. Better solution would be highly appreciated.
Thanks